# Access to Media Files inside Android/Media/ Folder - Android 11

Tags: android, storage, android-11

Which permission is required to read/write Pictures ad Video files inside file:///emulated/0/Android/Media folder in Android 11(API 30)?

Comment: That path does not exist.

Comment: In API 30 ot high you have access to public dir DCMA and Download (?) without permission by ContentResolver.